# Execute code before creating document in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

How can I execute some code only when a document is created in mongoengine, not when updated.

```py
class Account(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=80, default=None)
    username = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'accounts'
    }
```

Now I want to generate random username and assign it to the username field before a document is created.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the [MongoEngine's signals](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html#overview) - `pre_save()` sounds like a good fit. There are [different ways](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html#attaching-events) to attach an event handler to a signal, here is one of them:

```
from mongoengine import signals

class Account(Document):
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.username = "random username"

signals.pre_save.connect(Account.pre_save, sender=Account)
```

Comment: I think `pre_save` is called while updating as well, and I don't want to execute my code every time document is saved, just once when It's created.

Comment: @RohitKhatri ah, gotcha..then `pre_init()` might be a good fit.

Comment: how can I access the document fields in pre_init signal handler, because when I try to access document property name, It throws error `AttributeError: _data`

Comment: @RohitKhatri I've not personally used `pre_init()` before and expected setting the fields via `document.field` work..okay, can you try with `post_init()`? Thanks.

Comment: I accomplished this by using `post_init` and executed my code If the `document.id` is `None`